# Unable To Update SQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

$staffid = $_GET['staffid'];

$query = "SELECT active FROM staff WHERE staffid = '$staffid'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$status = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

//echo $status['active'];

if ($status['active'] = '0') {
    "UPDATE staff
        SET active ='1'
        WHERE staffid = '$staffid' ";
} else {
    "UPDATE staff 
        SET active ='0'
        WHERE staffid = '$staffid'";
}
```

Here is my code, I'm able to echo the "Active Status" 0 Or 1 But I'm unable to update based on the if else statement.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although I would recommend using prepared statements for safety, you can do this in 1 update rather than 2 out of 3 statements, just update the status to 1 minus the current status

```
$query = "UPDATE staff SET active = 1 - active WHERE staffid = '$staffid'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should really be using prepared statements. If all you want to do is flip a boolean flag in the database, you can use one query.

```
// enable error reporting and connect
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$link = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
$link->set_charset('utf8mb4');

// prepare -> bind -> execute
$stmt = $link->prepare('UPDATE staff SET active=!active WHERE staffid=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['staffid']);
$stmt->execute();
```

If you also would like to fetch the value, you can also use prepared statement.

```
$stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT active FROM staff WHERE staffid=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['staffid']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$status = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $status['active'];
```

You should also learn more about MySQLi error reporting: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

By the way, your original problem was that you used single equals, which is an assignement operator, not comparison, in the if statement `$status['active'] = '0'`